# How to create two barplots of unequal height (different max values) in R but with the same units on the Y axis?

Tags: r, layout, graph, bar-chart

Is it possible to make barplots (two) of unequal size (different max values on Y axis) but equal units (count data)?

The data is count data of the number of nesting attempts per season. Each species has 7 seasons of data. My objective is to present the data as clearly as possible for the reader to show the increase in the number of each of the two species nesting season on season. Although the initial pattern of increase is similar for both species, the number of species 1 nesting rises more rapidly. Plotting both sets of data on the same barplot is not a good option because the 7 seasons of data are not concurrent for the two species - rather it is the first 7 years of colonisation for each species (eg the labels on the x axis are different for the two species)

I have tried par(fig) and layout but not yet achieved what I need and I am not sure which function is better suited to what I need. Any advice welcome

Two barplots, one above the other, each taking up half the window. The Y units are the same for both graphs but the maximum for one is 300 whilst the other is 900. When they are plotted a count of 100 looks very different on the two graphs

```
SPECIES1 <- c(2,12,44,153,451,857)
SPECIES2 <- c(4,15,35,54,63,243)

windows(11,12)
par(oma=c(3,0.1,1,0.1),mfrow=c(2,1),mar=c(2,6,2,2.1))

barplot(SPECIES2,space=c(0.1,0),ylim=c(0,300),col="black",axes=FALSE)
axis(2,at=seq(0,300,100),las=2, cex.axis=0.9)

barplot(SPECIES1,space=c(0.1,0),ylim=c(0,900), col="black",border=NA,axes=FALSE )axis(2,at=seq(0,900,100),las=2,cex.axis=0.9)
```

[image: S]

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimial, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. Also discuss what you're trying to analyze, i.e. why do you want to compare the maximum values of two variables? If the variable(s) in question are at the interval / ratio level of measurement, a better alternative might be a boxplot, which compares means and various percentiles across multiple variables (or groups within a variable). What inferences / conclusions do you want the viewer to draw from the chart?

Comment: I hope that the edits have made my question clearer, but please let me know if I have missed anything. It is a very basic couple of graphs and I am almost ashamed to ask for help on given the fantastic plots R can produce, however I have been unable so far to find or work out a solution which combines the need for two graphs with equal Y units but unequal maximum values.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you go by using ggplot package

```
##   supp dose  len
## 1   VC D0.5  6.8
## 2   VC   D1 15.0
## 3   VC   D2 33.0
## 4   OJ D0.5  4.2
## 5   OJ   D1 10.0
## 6   OJ   D2 29.5

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

But you need third variable(supp in above case). Please provide Sample data which you want to plot for clear answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added sample data to the original question which hopefully makes the question clearer and easier to answer

Comment: Can you add sample output chart which you require?(You can draw it in paint just for two entries).